# webservice call without using system.IO class

Tags: c#, web-services

Is there any way to give the webRequest and Response without using streamReader and System.IO . My application does not accept system.IO. The application provides wrapper classes to call the webservice. But, i am not able to fetch the actual error from webservice through the wrapper classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Sta("http://www.google.com/");
```

Be sure to use the using

using System.net